# Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified targetSdkVersion31

Tags: android

the android:exported="true" existe in the AndroidManifest.xml file but always i have the same problem

Error: android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <activity>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details. AndroidV2.app main manifest (this file)

[Manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lljz4.png)

Comment: Check if there's any 3rd party lib who doesn't have exported tag in activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs after migrating the project to android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71584790/manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-see-logs-after-migrating-the-projec). Checkout my answer given there

Answer (score 0):

check out [merged manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests) case and tab in Android Studio (one and only screenshot under link), probably some library is adding own `Activity` or `Service` without declaring `exported` attribute. You can't force this attribute for not-own components, update your dependecies hoping author introduced this flag in current version or make a request for it (e.g. create an issue on github page)